# How do I update to Version 4.7 of KMyMoney from Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, kmymoney

I have tried the following steps and I am still in version 4.6.6.  I am a newbie to linux.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:claydoh/kmymoney2-kde4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install kmymoney
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Don't expect us to go and read random webpages in order to understand what you've done and help you. Please [edit] your question and include the steps you followed _here_.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Terdon.  I have edited the question with the steps I took.  Am interested in your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ubuntu is too old. Upgrade your system and the PPA (ppa:claydoh/kmymoney2-kde4, described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31462/how-do-i-update-to-the-most-recent-version-of-kmymoney)) will work.

---

Try the following, but I can not promise that it works with your Ubuntu version.

I quote [@terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon):

> If it fails, it will fail before the make install step and so will not
>   attempt to install anything. It is perfectly safe to try.

```
cd
wget http://download.kde.org/stable/kmymoney/4.7.2/src/kmymoney-4.7.2.tar.xz
tar xf kmymoney-4.7.2.tar.xz
sudo apt-get build-dep kmymoney
cd kmymoney-4.7.2
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
```

Install with:

- the classic way with `make install`

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```
- or with `checkinstall` for a deb package

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  sudo checkinstall
  ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23962/discussion-on-answer-by-a-b-how-do-i-update-to-version-4-7-of-kmymoney-from-ubu).